# Which HRESULT to return when a class doesn't implement a method for some design reason?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, error-handling

Suppose I have a not so well designed COM interface and some classes just logically can't implement one of its methods.

Like, for example, there's some method like `Explode()` and many classes just can't reasonably "explode" but still have to implement that method and need to return an appropriate error code.

Do I return `E_NOTIMPL` in such cases? To me this code means "***not yet implemented***, check back in version 2.0". Should it also be used when a method is permanently not implemented by a class for some serious design reason as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certainly add your own `HRESULT` for this but in my view it's perfectly valid to return `E_NOTIMPL` in this instance.  It's never been my understanding that `E_NOTIMPL` implied an intention to implement at some later date.